# On select of date on FullCalendar, the click accuracy is miscalibrated

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have not found another question quite like this.  There are some similar with solutions like "be sure and include 'prev' and 'next' buttons" and things about timezones etc.  I do not believe there is any issue with the logic or time zone or code on the backend.  When I click on existing events, they work fine.  I can click, drag, drop, edit, retrieve popup modal, etc.  But when I click on an empty space in a date, it is inaccurate.  I can see it visually selecting the wrong box.  This is the case for every day of the month.  The click is accurate in the top left 25% of the box.  The bottom and left 75% is off by one box in that direction.  [image: Look at 18th of May]

Look at May 18.
red:  works perfect
yellow:  selects 19th
blue:  selects 26th
green:  selects 25th

It is like a strange calibration issue.  But if I click on an event, even if it is at the bottom of that box, like Thomas on May 5, it works just fine.  Below is my js file.

```
function GetEventsOnPageLoad() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Today',
            month: 'Month',
            week: 'Week',
            day: 'Day'

        },

        selectable: true,
        select: function (start) {
            selectedEvent = {
                eventID: 0,
                start: start,
                allDay: true,
            };
            CreateFullCalEvent(start.toISOString());
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        height: 'parent',
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "GetEventData",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    var events = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                        events.push(
                            {
                                title: data.title,
                                start: moment(data.start),
                                end: moment(data.end),
                                allDay: true,
                                backgroundColor: data.color,
                                id: data.id,
                                textColor: data.textColor


                            }
                        );
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            })
        },
        nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        eventClick: function (info) {
            GetFullCalEventByID(info);
        },
        eventDrop: function (info) {
            console.log(info);
            UpdateFullCalEvent(info.id, info.start.toISOString(), info.end.toISOString());
        },
        eventResize: function (info) {
            UpdateFullCalEvent(info.id, info.start.toISOString(), info.end.toISOString());
        }
    })
}


function CreateFullCalEvent(start) {
    window.location.href = "CreateFullCalEvent?start=" + encodeURIComponent(start);

}

function GetFullCalEventByID(eventinfo) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GetFullCalEventByID/" + eventinfo.id,
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "applicaton/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (eventdetails) {
            showModal('Event Details', eventdetails, true);
        }
    });
}
function UpdateFullCalEvent(id, start, end) {
    var object = {};
    object.id = id;
    object.start = start;
    object.end = end;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "UpdateFullCalEvent/",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify(object)
    });

}
function showModal(title, body, isEventDetail) {
    $("MyPopup .modal-title").html(title);

    if (isEventDetail == null) {
        $("#MyPopup .modal-body").html(body);
        $("#MyPopup").modal("show");
    }
    else {
        var title = 'Title: ' + body.title + '</br>';
        var details = 'Details: ' + body.details + '</br>';
        var date = 'Date: ' + moment(body.start).format("M/D/YYYY") + '</br>';
        var empName = 'Employee: ' + body.employeeName + '</br>';
        url = 'Location: ' + body.url + '</br>';
        var modalPop = $("#MyPopup .modal-body");

        modalPop.html(title + details + date + empName + url);
        $("#MyPopup.modal").modal("show");
    }
}
```

About line 16 to 21 is the issue.  It happens even if I am not calling a function at all.  If I just do a popup modal like below, I can still see it highlighting and selecting the wrong day:

```
 selectable: true,
        select: function () {
            showModal('Create an Event', 'Create new Event feature coming soon.  For now, use create button in list view', null);
```

Comment: The most likely reason for such a thing is that your page's CSS is interfering with the positioning of the calendar elements somehow. I made a demo which doesn't reproduce the issue using plain fullCalendar with no other CSS on the page: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyvXyWv . Obviously I had to guess at the height of the parent element (which might be relevant, but I suspect not). Try removing CSS rules and/or changing them so they won't affect fullCalendar, and see if that helps

Comment: One way to know if the previous comment situation is happening, you can browser inspect the CSS to see if what is set for the style is what you expect to see.

Comment: @ADyson.  You two were right.  It was the CSS.  I had .body { zoom:  110%;} for other reasons.  I had removed it, but it was still showing on inspect.  Saved in cache.  Thank you! Paul, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS was the issue.  I had

```
 body  {
     zoom:  110%;
 }
```

Apparently fullCalendar does not respond well to zoom feature of CSS.  It is not a problem if the user zooms in the browser though.